# How to rewrite a url in which values have been passed by get method and pass them to another page?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using Xampp and did almost everything. 
I have the htaccess file as follows :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^q? query.php [NC]
```

Moreover, I have switched ON mod_rewrite module and  changed all the `Allow None` to `Allow All` in the `http.conf` Apache File.

I want my the url to be `localhost/abc/query.php?q=something&c=something` instead of `localhost/q?q=something&c=something`

PS: Its not a typo, ('q')page is actually without extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule should work for you in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^q/?$ /abc/query.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava... It worked, made a silly mistake of not putting '$' sign in the regular expression... :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are using q/index.php and that's why the extension is hidden because index.php gets hidden. What you wanna do is:

```
<form action="abc/query.php" name="query" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="q" />
<input type="text" name="c" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

And then it should show up as `/abc/query.php?q=randomtext&c=randomtext` .